# $filter('date')(milliSecond, 'HH:mm:ss, mm/dd/yyyy'); returns wrong date when time zone is changed

Tags: angularjs

I am working in java script's AngularJs.js framework.

I am using `$filter` service to **convert milliseconds into corresponding date**.
But when I change the time zone its corresponding date is changed(different to previous).

following is code.

```
$filter('date')(milliSecond, 'HH:mm:ss, mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: can any one help me.............

Comment: angular deals with local time zone, when you display date time its converted in local time zone and then displayed on page. So, when you select date time convert that to UTC and then store in DB.

Comment: You should also post your current result, and your expected result.

Comment: Location: Kolkata --> 06/23/2015, 05:06:40 PM

Comment: when set time zone Jima

Answer (score 1):

Calculate millisecond to local millisecond

```
milliSecondLocal = milliSecond - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;

$filter('date')(milliSecondLocal, 'HH:mm:ss, mm/dd/yyyy');
```